# not preserving the sequence after the query is executed in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, group-concat

I am using a query to insert the records in a table attendance_student but when the query executed it do not preserve the sequence in att_punch. preserve means as in the query 'ss' is coming at the last in att_punch it should be at last but when it is executed and records are saved 'ss' comes at first place in att_punch it may be due to it is grouping in ascending order but i want to preserve the sequence. Is there any way to do that. here is what i tried this code does not preserve the sequence

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

INSERT INTO attendance_student (class_id, month_id, attendance_details, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT 
  class_id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(attendance_date, '%m') AS month_id, 
  CONCAT('[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        '{"att_date": "', DATE_FORMAT(attendance_date, '%d-%m-%Y'), '",',
        '"att_status": "', attendance_status, '",',
        '"att_punch": ', IFNULL(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
          'did', '0',
          'pat', IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), ''),
          'ss', IFNULL(bio_punch_details, '')
        )), JSON_ARRAY()), '}'
      ) ORDER BY attendance_date -- Added order by attendance_date
      SEPARATOR ',\n'
    )
    , IFNULL(CONCAT(', {"ss": "', IFNULL(bio_punch_details, ''), '"}'), '') -- Added screenshot details
    , ']'
  ) AS attendance_details, 
  NOW() AS created_at, 
  NOW() AS updated_at
FROM student_attendance_daily
GROUP BY class_id,month_id;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: @RohitGupta You can see the sequence in att_punch that 'did' is first place, 'pat' is at second place and 'ss' is at third place but when i execute the query and when i see in column of table it shows that 'ss' is at first place, 'did' is at second place and 'pat' is at third place. I am trying my best to solve this. Is this an geniune issue or may be in future. My Senior is forcing me to preserve the sequence that i am unable to figure out what to do next. can you help me